# Retrieve data from db with foreign key constraint

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am getting an error while fetching data from db.The error is like this:-

```
{"Invalid column name 'Amount_Value'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Amount_Currency'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Amount_Value'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Amount_Currency'."}
```

Here is my main model of "Deals":-

```
public class Deal {

   public long ID { get; set; }

   [StringLength(1024),Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

   public Client Party { get; set; }
   public long PartyID { get; set; }


   public DateTime Created { get; set; }
   public long Version { get; set; }

   [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
   public string Notes { get; set; }

   public Money Amount { get; set; }
   public DealKindEnum Mode { get; set; }
  }
```

Here "Money" is another class which is like this:-

```
public class Money
{
 [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
 public double Value { get; set; }
 public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting error while using this query:--

```
var query = from client in db.Clients
 join ra in db.Deals on client.ID equals ra.PartyID
 where (ra.ID == id || id == 0)
 select ra;
```

Comment: So Money is not an Entity   => doesn't exist in db ? If it is, I think your property should be virtual. `public virtual Money Amount {get;set;}` If it's not, you should mark with  `NotMappedAttribute` (`[NotMapped]` on property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF can't do anything with properties which are not in database.
From your comment, Money is not an entity.

So you have to mark the property in Deal class as NotMapped

```
[NotMapped]
public Money Amount { get; set; }
```

And EF won't try to get anything from db while querying.
Of course, you won't have anything in Amount property, but how could you if it's not in db...

Comment: Thanks it worked and please see my another question which I edited in this question only.

Comment: @AkankshaT you should rather let your question as it was and ask a new one. Or anyone looking at this one won't understand anything !

Comment: Sorry.I am doing that.